# Maven: Red Line when inherit parent project "spring-boot-starter-parent"

Tags: spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I was trying to build my very first SpringBoot project on IDEA. When setting up the pom.xml file, I got the following red lines. I've searched about it but cannot find a answer. Can someone give a hint about this. [the red lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD8p1.png)
By the way, I have jdk and maven installed.

I tried some other version, but it doesn't work. I tried code from online tutorial but still got the red line.

Comment: Try clicking on the m⟳ symbol which popped up in the right top corner as shown in your snap.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve the issue try deleting the content of your local maven repository located in (C:\Users\win10.m2).

Also, make sure to Rebuild your maven project and let it download all dependencies from remote repository.

Comment: Thank you! Issue solved by click the ⟳ reload symbol